# KeyError inside a def function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I am transforming some data and I found myself in the situation where I needed to repeat the same process across different dataframes so I thought that building a function would be great.

I started doing this:

```py
count_words = lambda x: len(x)
index = 'word_count'
values= ['Search term', 'Clicks', 'Impr.']

def table_transformation(dataframe, index, values):
    dataframe_to_pivot = pd.pivot_table(data= dataframe,
                                        index= index,
                                        values= values,
                                        aggfunc= {values[0]: count_words,
                                                  values[1]: np.sum,
                                                  values[2]: np.sum}
                                       )
    
    dataframe_to_pivot.sort_values(by=[index], ascending= True)
    sum_counts = dataframe_to_pivot.iloc[9:].sum()
    dataframe_to_pivot.drop(dataframe_to_pivot.index[9:].tolist())
    dataframe_to_pivot.loc['+10'] = sum_counts
    return dataframe_to_pivot

fy21_word_counts = fy21.apply(table_transformation, args=(index, values))
fy21_word_counts
```

I got a `KeyError: 'Search term' error`.

What I tried:

- I tried inserting the actual names of the columns inside the function but got the same error
- the logic inside the function works outside the function's `def()` structure

What is it that I overlooked/ misunderstood?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html), because need pass DataFrame instead apply function for each column by `.apply`:

```
fy21_word_counts = fy21.pipe(table_transformation, index, values)
```

Comment: Your answer is the right one, almost. What worked for me was to use: 
`fy21_word_counts = fy21.pipe(table_transformation, index, values)`

Comment: Also, @jezrael, what would be the difference between `df.pipe` and `df.apply`?

Comment: @Osaka - [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) if method for apply function per columns/ per rows (axis=1). If use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) it apply function to all columns together, like `table_transformation(fy21)`